# 'trySilentLogin' of 'Google Plus' is resulting in error code '4', while 'login' is working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I'm trying to use logout() of GooglePlus cordova plugin, but before that, I'm using 'trySilentLogin()'.

'trySilentLogin()' is giving me error code of 4 while I'm able to 'login()' successfully.

Can anyone please help me in resolving this.

I've googled a lot and verified that I'm using correct webClientID and consent screen has project name & email id saved too.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.   You may also consider contacting the author of your plugin

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `offline` as **false**  in  options, [further information](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus#try-silent-login)

```
this.googleplus.trySilentLogin({

    offline: false
})
.then(
    res => {
        console.log(res);

        ...
        "ur logic"
        ...
     }
)
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

this worked for me